# How to beat Harada Tekken?

Tags: soul-calibur-5

How can you beat the Harada Tekken bonus character in Soul Calibur 5?  I have tried every character, and I am rather proficient in most of them, but he performs a moveset that is literally impossible to do as a human person.

He can chain together 4 lightning strikes, which is not possible for a human player to do,
That being said, how can you beat him?  When the computer cheats, the only way to win is to be cheap about it.

So what strategy works the best against him?  I cannot, for the life of me, defeat him.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm actually gonna post a strategy I came up to beat higher level AI in this game with Viola.

**The Sequence and the Attack String**
(remember, I'm assuming you've learned Viola's tools before you attempt to apply this)

-Set the orb

I'm partial to With Orb 6B+K for both it's speed and the fact that you can follow it up quickly with the upcoming string

-Use the attack string

(Orb Set) BBB(last press brings the orb back)->(With Orb) 8A+B->(Orb Set) 6B+K(taps them from behind and keeps the orb set)

-Dash in close and repeat from the BBB on until they drop

-Use her other tools to mix things up

In general, keep to fast attacks and mixing up attack heights to make sure they don't have a chance to breathe(like following the string with 1A+B, which leaps into a low knock down attack)

How do you know this works?

BBB is one of Viola's fastest attacks and stuffs alot of the stuff the AI tries to do to cheese you out, like many of Cervante's moves. With Mitsurugi, my losses were in double digits against MCZ Kayane before I finally came out on top; With Viola, I not only beat her on my first try, I actually got a ring out and a Perfect, not to mention I tore through pretty much everyone else, cut my Legendary Souls time down to just under 7 minutes. Obviously, the rule with things like this is "pics or it didn't happen," so here's the proof: http://t.co/DefIAaqR Although this method helped me jump several levels, I also ran into a few rough patches along the way. Like what, you may be thinking?

**Things to keep in mind about the string/Viola**

- Getting thrown or hit by anything (except light taps) will auto set the orb, which, for the string, is a good thing
- Even if they block the whole time, they'll likely be aggro enough to let the last hit of 8A+B catch them.

I've only seen the AI block the entire string once...on Normal, and considering the numerous harder AI it tore through, I'd say it's a good chance they won't be able to stay on their feet long

- If it's near a wall or the edge of the ring, the last hit of 8A+B is likely to catch that and whiff(if both hits of it land when they're near the edge of the ring, though, a Ring Out is almost a lock).

If you wanna make it safer, sub 8A+B out with another orb setting move, like 2A+B(hits ducking opponents and can be delayed by charging)

- If the opponent is run happy(like Aris's AI, which is where I discovered the rough patch in the string), sub out BBB with a move that smacks them out of their run

This includes Orb Set 22\88 AB(which brings the orb back and lets you continue the attack string into 8A+B) and Orb Set 4A+B(which is slightly slower and not conductive to creating the stream of offense needed to make Viola formidable)

- If you're not on top of them with the string/you're not using the whole of Viola's tricks and spacing tools to throw them off, the computer will smack you around without remorse.

Answer (score 1):

The way I see games like these (MK9 is a huge example of cheap strategies.)

If the computer is showing signs of being cheap as hell, fight fire with fire. other than that backing off till you find an opening and using your most practised chain combos will surely give you some sort of edge. its all about timing. I'll elaborate on fight fire with fire, if you know a move or string of moves that is cheap but is the only way to defeat this character then I would find no remorse in using their own medicine against them.

That's the best advice I can give.

I apply that same principle online. if someone is being cheap they are going to get a taste of Spam attacks :P

Comment: Unfortunately, he is cheap in a way that is impossible for me to replicate.

Comment: can you not block his attacks and wait for an opening as suggested? that's the way most of those type of games work

Comment: I think this is the best advice I am going to get, accepting.

Answer (score 1):

OK I got a fairly easy answer. Just use Yoshimitsu and use (Xbox controls) continually hold up the right analog stick and press x. When he gets into the air/ says ascend, press Y. Keep doing this. You should always also try and make sure you direct yourself towards Harada  before going airbourne.

EDIT: OK I was unclear. (Hold up right analog stick for the entire time). Press x. Don't press another button ( you should still be holding right analog stick upwards) until he finishes spinning/ says the word ascend. Then press Y. You can still let go of the stick in order to use critical/ special move but this opens a huge gap( I would not reccomend using critical edge). These controls are in Xbox 360 and can be changed to suit other consoles.